# Count the number of missing values in each column and sort them

Tags: python

I am a very beginner. learning online courses. Can somebody please help me figure out what to fill in the blank? It required "Order them (increasing or decreasing) using sort_values".
missing.sort_values(by=___)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort with the missing numbers `NaN` first you can specify `na_position='first'` (the default value is last).

```
missing.sort_values(by=['column_name'] ,na_position='first')
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is my first question I asked here.

Comment: You're welcome. Does that help?

Comment: @ Kendle very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "missing" is a python DataFrame, you can sort_values by a column.

For example,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, 'D', 'C'],
...     'col2': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
...     'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
...     'col4': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F']
... })

>>> df
  col1  col2  col3 col4
0    A     2     0    a
1    A     1     1    B
2    B     9     9    c
3  NaN     8     4    D
4    D     7     2    e
5    C     4     3    F

>>> df.sort_values(by=['col1'])
>>> df

  col1  col2  col3 col4
0    A     2     0    a
1    A     1     1    B
2    B     9     9    c
5    C     4     3    F
4    D     7     2    e
3  NaN     8     4    D
```

For further reference, you can see the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: Glad I could help! If the answer solved the question, please consider accepting it!